# 15 puzzle problem using Branch and Bound

Tags: puzzle, branching-rules

As per my knowledge, the node which having the least cost is **branched** in branch and bound approach to solve n puzzle problem.

What happens if there are **multiple nodes with minimal cost** ??

Any of the node is taken or every node must be branched ?